# How to focus multiselect on tab key in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, multi-select

I am using a multiselect control in my page (xtype: Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect).
when I am using tab to switch from one control to another, it is skipping multiselect control.
How can I focus multiselect control, when I use tab key?

**UPDATE**: Sample code below

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox'
                },
                width: 400,
                minHeight:200,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                border: 1,
                style: { borderColor: '#000000', borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: '1px' },
                defaults: {
                    labelWidth: 80,
                    style: {
                        padding: '10px'
                    }
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    name: 'startDate',
                    fieldLabel: 'Start date'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'multiselect',
                    name: 'multi select',
                    fieldLabel: 'multiSelect',
                    store: [[123,'One Hundred Twenty Three'],
                            ['1', 'One'], ['2', 'Two'], ['3', 'Three'], ['4', 'Four'], ['5', 'Five'],
                            ['6', 'Six'], ['7', 'Seven']
                            ]

                }, {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    name: 'endDate',
                    fieldLabel: 'End date'
                }]
            });
```

Comment: it is skipping multiselect control???? Do you mean all your selected values are getting lost?

Comment: yes, it is skipping multiselect control and jumping to next control. say, My page contains 3 ctrls textbox, multiselect, date, if i press tab key while I am in textbox , it skips multiselect and focus on date ctrl. not loosing any data.

Comment: I think ExtJS has not provided property 'tabIndex' for MultiSelect. Also this kind of issue is present in case of Grid.